# IIFE function runs twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, webpack

I wanted to try out typescript and webpack i put some code in an IIFE and it runs twice.  I increment a counter and it increments once, but in the browser it outputs twice.  So i get 6 rows instead of 3.  I thought this might have been a side effect of webpack dev server or something so i mocked up same code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n3cosgvr/).  It works as expected there.

So i did a build of the code locally with webpack and ran http-server on it and it still outputs twice.

```
let isInit = true;
let counter = 0;

const lcAppdata = {

    matters: [{
        mid: 100,
        title: "Matter1",
        dateOpened: "01/01/17",
        decedent: "Elvis Presley",
        personalRepresentative: "Alexis Texas",
        attorneyAccountInfo: "John Holmes"
    }, {
        mid: 200,
        title: "Matter2",
        dateOpened: "01/02/16",
        decedent: "Kurt Cobain",
        personalRepresentative: "Kagney Linn Karter",
        attorneyAccountInfo: "Simon Rex"
    }, {
        mid: 300,
        title: "Matter3",
        dateOpened: "01/03/15",
        decedent: "Bob Marley",
        personalRepresentative: "Nikki Benz",
        attorneyAccountInfo: "Ron Jeremy"
    }],
    currentMatter: ''
};


(function init(){
    for(let matter of lcAppdata.matters){
        $('#tbodyMatterList').append(`<tr ><th scope="row" >${matter.title}</th>
            <td bind>${matter.decedent}</td>
            <td bind>${matter.dateOpened}</td>
            <td bind>${matter.personalRepresentative}</td>
            <td bind>${matter.attorneyAccountInfo}</td></tr>`);
        console.log(matter.title);
    }
    counter++;

    console.log(counter);


})();
```

console output:

```
Matter1
Matter2
Matter3
1
Matter1
Matter2
Matter3
1
```

Not sure where to go from here, it seems to only get quasi-executed?  The counter only gets incremented once?  Though displayed twice?

Comment: Are you sure `init()` isn't called anywhere? What happens if just write `function()` instead of `function init()`?

Comment: Sounds like you're loading the script twice somehow. Put some logging at the top and bottom of the script.

Comment: yep, logging shows that I am.  i guess that would be a webpack misconfiguration somehow.